# serialize objects after you terminate program

Tags: java, database, serialization, terminate

I'm familiar with the process of serializing an object and writing it to a file, but is there a way tp dp so after the user terminates the console?

Comment: Huh?  Needs a lot more detail, please.

Comment: Sure there is. One way would be to simply keep a `Collection` of the objects that have been modified during runtime. Then, on program close, simply serialize all objects. Can't really help without more context though :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could add [SIGTERM](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html) handler. In java you can do it by using [Runtime.addShutdownHook()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29)

Comment: i tested this method with intellij ide and noticed sgutDownHook doesn't work with it's stop button(ctrl+f2). is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Probably intellij sends other signal when you click stop button and I guess they are using the same methods as you could use in the terminal. How about checking their site fos some tips? If it is possible, then it should documented somewhere